# How can I run a command that requires user input through oh-my-zsh alias?

Tags: terminal, command-line, automator, reminders, zsh

I'm trying to add Reminder.app items through the command line by invoking an alias. I use the Automator workflow solution from this question: [How can I add reminders via the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66981/how-can-i-add-reminders-via-the-command-line), which invokes a basic workflow containing an empty Reminders item, via the following command line input:

```
automator -i remindertext add_reminder.workflow
```

This works perfectly, but is clumsy to type, so I want to set an alias for it. My question is: how do I set an alias in .zshrc that allows for me to set the reminder item text when I invoke the alias? It would basically need to be able to replace 'remindertext' with a variable, like so:

```
alias reminder='automator -i <variable> add_reminder.workflow'
```

Is this possible in zsh/oh-my-zsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases are used as a shortcuts - sipmple commands that expand to longer ones.
If you need to pass an argument to it, you would need to create a function.
Maybe try something like:

```
reminder () { automator -i $1 add_reminder.workflow' }
```

Here $1 will expand to the first argument that you've passed to the function.
So you'll to do something like:

```
reminder "Buy potatoes"
```

P.S: I haven't tried it, since I don't have zsh with me right now, so if it breaks, give me a shout.

Comment: Thanks! This set me in the right direction, with some minor tinkering. I now have this line in my .zshrc file:

`function reminder () {automator -i $1 add_reminder.workflow}`

Works perfectly.

Comment: Wanted to add that after playing with the syntax a bit, I realized that it also works without adding the 'function' part at the beginning of the line (i.e., it works precisely like Atanas suggested it would with his code)

Comment: I am trying to type  `weather() { curl -4 http://wttr.in/$1 }` to enable `weather newyork` alias, the original command is `curl -4 http://wttr.in/newyork`

Comment: @Wongzigii: (1) You've missed ; between $1 and } (2) It's better to use ${1:-newyork}, in this case if you start `weather`, newyork is used by default, and you can specify additional parameters if you want override it; (3) you don't need -4 anymore, it works even so no; (4) I would suggest use `wttr` instead of `weather` for the function name: it's short and unique and it's obvious what it means